# Java Guessing Game looping error

Tags: java, exception

I am having a problem with a simple game I am trying to create. I'm sure it is just a simple error, but I can't seem to get it. Two errors actually, one is that it doesn't increment `numOfTries` after every time it goes through, and another is that it doesn't handle exceptions correctly. I want it to output a string when the input is not an integer. How to fix both the errors?

```
/*
 * Guessing game
 */

import java.util.*;

public class GuessNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        guess(input);
        System.out.println("You got it correct after " + guess(input) + " tries");
    }

    public static int guess(Scanner input) {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        int numToGuess = randomNumber.nextInt(10);
        int numOfTries = 0;
        String prompt = "Enter your guess (integer from 1 to 10)";
        numOfTries++;
        getInt(input, prompt);
        if (getInt(input, prompt) == numToGuess) {
            return numOfTries;
        } else if (getInt(input, prompt) != numToGuess) {
            getInt(input, prompt);
        }
        return numOfTries;
    }

    public static int getInt(Scanner input, String prompt) {
        int userGuess = 0;
        System.out.println(prompt);
        try {
            userGuess = input.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You didn't enter an int");
        }
        return userGuess;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "correctly" in terms of exception handling.

Comment: Assign the return value of your first call to `guess(input) ` to a variable, and use that variable in your println call instead of calling guess again.

Comment: You are calling methods again instead of keeping around results in variables. It's not just `guess(input)`, it's also `getInt(input,prompt)`. Call it again - and it will do all the steps again, and that's not what you want. Also, you don't have a loop, and without that you can't do the "try again" part.

Comment: I have reworded the question for better readability and added appropriate tags. Glad that your question has been answered. Now that you know whats wrong with the please try to make title more specific. Go through the examples of good titles [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. You call guess() twice two different times. The local variables in the function to not keep their values between function calls, so that might be your reason why you don't think numTries is being incremented. Also, by calling it twice, you force the user to guess for two possibly different random numbers (aka you play the game twice). You have the same problem with getInt() as well.
2. The way you are calling nextInt(10) will give you a number between 0 and 9 inclusive. You will never get 10, and the person will never guess 0 because the prompt tells him not to.
3. Each time you call guess, you are only letting the user try once, so numTries is being incremented and returned, but only once, yielding a return value of 1 every time. To let the user guess multiple times, put a while loop in.
4. When you have the exception handling, you should put it in a loop so that the user enters input until a valid int is entered.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int guesses = guess(input);
       System.out.println("You got it correct after " + guesses + " tries");
   }

   public static int guess(Scanner input)
   {
       String prompt = "Enter your guess (integer from 1 to 10)";
       Random randomNumber = new Random();
       numToGuess = randomNumber.nextInt(10) + 1;    //+1 to make it 1-10 inclusive
       numTries = 0;

       while (getInt(input, prompt) != numToGuess)
       {
           numTries++;
       }

       return numTries;
   }

   public static int getInt(Scanner input, String prompt)
   {
       int userGuess = -1;
       boolean valid = false;
       System.out.println(prompt);

       while (!valid)
       {
           try
           {
               userGuess = input.nextInt();
               valid = true;
           }
           catch (NumberFormatException e)
           {
               System.out.println("You did not enter an int. Try again");
           }
       }

       return userGuess;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I knew it was some logic error. THANK YOU!